# Open Google Maps App from Ionic2 App using link

Tags: google-maps, ionic2, mobile-application

I am writing a simple application using Ionic2 and Angular2.

I just want to type an address in my app, and then go to Google App on my phone
(I don't want to have map in my app just open another app).

I read that it is possible using link`<a href="google.navigation:q=London">London</a>`

which works perfectly in webApp.
Is it a possible to use it in a Mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

I am taking you would like to open Google Maps App to navigate to a place based on the link you have given.

You can use this plugin: https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator

and call it like this: `launchnavigator.navigate("London, UK");` to navigate to a destination address from current location. Other API calls can be found in the readme file.